# Printing lines from a file using an input file that contains the line numbers

Tags: unix, awk, grep

I have a file `numbers.txt` that contains a number on every line.

I want to use that file to print out the lines in the file `lines.txt`, i.e. the lines that correspond to the numbers in `numbers.txt`.

Can this be done with `awk`, or some other way directly in the Unix command line?

Example:

`numbers.txt`:

```
1
2
4
6
```

`lines.txt`:

```
1: line one
2: line two
3: line three
...
6: line six
```

Output:

```
1: line one
2: line two
4: line four
6: line six
```

Comment: I have never tried any such thing, but read this http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/186639-compare-values-two-files-matching-rows-print-corresponding-values-file-1-file2.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this awk one-liner:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{n[$0];next}FNR in n' numbers.txt lines.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this command to output line `n` in the file `lines.txt`:

```
 cat lines.txt | head -<n> | tail -1
```

And then do it for all the lines in the `numbers.txt` as your `n`:

```
 for n in `cat numbers.txt`; do cat lines.txt | head -$n | tail -1; done;
```

Note: If there's no line in `lines.txt` corresponding to a number, it will output the last line in the file instead; you'd need an additional test to check and avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

```
 parallel -ka numbers.txt 'sed -n {}p lines.txt'
```

[Here](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html) is more info about *parallel*

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F":" 'FNR=NR{a[$0];next}($1 in a){print}' numbers.txt lines.txt
```

Comment: `=`instead of `==`, unnecessary parens and unnecessary `{print}`.